CMake ExternalProject cache
I'm including SQLite3 with ExternalProject. I'm using Ninja back-end. My problem is that every time I do a clean, SQLite3 has to be rebuilt and it unnecessarily slows down builds. The library has only to be built once for all build types, unless it's updated to a new version.
If there's not anything better, I guess I could write a wrapper script that would copy libsqlite3.a to a /cache directory in the project root and copy it to proper location instead of calling make if it's found. Does CMake provide a built-in mechanism for that though?
The relevant part of the config is:
ExternalProject_Add(
  sqlite3
  URL https://www.sqlite.org/2024/sqlite-src-3460100.zip
  URL_HASH SHA3_256=23fdf1ebc809971e73fa7875c1cc9f854f4c2274446f4f4a18c9fa2ec6cae12e
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND <INSTALL_DIR>/src/sqlite3/configure
  BUILD_COMMAND make
  INSTALL_COMMAND cmake -E echo "Skipping install step."
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
  # Note that normally there should be a /bld/ subdir preceeding .libs, the object files seem to
  # be generated right along source files. It is not a problem, however.
  BUILD_BYPRODUCTS <INSTALL_DIR>/src/sqlite3/.libs/libsqlite3.a
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(sqlite3 install_dir)

add_library(sqlite3-lib STATIC IMPORTED)
add_dependencies(sqlite3-lib sqlite3)

set_target_properties(sqlite3-lib PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${install_dir}/src/sqlite3/.libs/libsqlite3.a
)

add_dependencies(MyProject sqlite3-lib)

I also had it setup earlier with FetchContent, which seemed to preserve the lib after clean for some reason. However, I could not get it to work with Ninja which complained about libsqlite3.a not being provided and it seemed like ExternalProject is the more proper way to do this. Anyway, this is the FetchContent code I used earlier if relevant:
FetchContent_Declare(
  sqlite3
  URL https://www.sqlite.org/2024/sqlite-src-3460100.zip
  URL_HASH SHA3_256=23fdf1ebc809971e73fa7875c1cc9f854f4c2274446f4f4a18c9fa2ec6cae12e
  DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP true
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(sqlite3)

set(SQLITE3_LIB "${sqlite3_SOURCE_DIR}/bld/.libs/libsqlite3.a")

if(NOT EXISTS ${SQLITE3_LIB})
  add_custom_target(build_sqlite3
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory "${sqlite3_SOURCE_DIR}/bld"

    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E chdir "${sqlite3_SOURCE_DIR}/bld" ${sqlite3_SOURCE_DIR}/configure
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E chdir "${sqlite3_SOURCE_DIR}/bld" make

    DEPENDS ${sqlite3_SOURCE_DIR}/configure
  )
else()
  add_custom_target(build_sqlite3)
endif()

add_library(sqlite3 STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(sqlite3 PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${SQLITE3_LIB}"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${sqlite3_SOURCE_DIR}"
)

add_dependencies(MyProject build_sqlite3)

